# NSPopover in NSCollectionView (or not)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nscollectionview, nspopover

I have a custom subclass of `NSView` that is used in an `NSCollectionView`.
The view shows a `NSPopover` when it is double clicked using the code below:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [super mouseDown:theEvent];
    if ([theEvent clickCount] == 2) {
        [popover showRelativeToRect:[self bounds] ofView:self preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
    }
}
```

`popover` is an `IBOutlet` (yes it's connected).

This works fine when the view is placed in a window normally, but when the view is in the collection view, it doesn't show.

`[popover showRelativeToRect:[self bounds] ofView:self preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge]` is indeed called (I set a breakpoint) and no errors are logged.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does the collection view accept input?  If it does not accept first responder, then your subview won't see the click.